# How to force an NSTextField to accept the text?

Tags: objective-c, keypress, nstextfield

I have an NSTextField in a Preferences panel. It provides a field to enter a url in.
However, if the user closes the Preferences panel after editing the text in the field, the new value does *not* get propagated to the User Defaults. This only happens after the user explicitly does Enter or Tab.
This kind of makes the whole approach useless, it seems to me, so I guess I must be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix this by setting the firstResponder to nil when the window closes.

```
[[self window] makeFirstResponder:nil];
```